# SvelteKit: how to check if environment is isomorphic or server-only?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Is it possible to check whether we are in isomorphic environment (ie. a `routes/**/*.svelte` file) or in server-only environment (ie a `routes/**/*.ts`)?

I have a function that run either in a `.svelte` page or a `.ts` api endpoint but I want it to behave differently depending on the context.

I checked all variables in `$app/env` but none of them give the information I need.

**EDIT: CONTEXT**

I'm creating a RPC (remote process control) framework that make server-client communication a breeze. The idea is: you can call a function from a distant server like any function- and it is typed.

When using a framework like SvelteKit, things get a bit complicated because you can call this distant-server function from either the browser (at hydration time) or from the SvelteKit server. There are two possible situations:

- a distant-server call from a page. We are in an isomorphic environment: the code is executed twice, first in the server then in the browser when hydrating. In this case, I want to dismiss the distant-server call from the SvelteKit *server* environment, since it would have no effect. I only want the *browser* call to work. That is done using the $app/env::browser  environment variable;
- a distant-server call from a SvelteKit's endpoint. This time, the call is executed only in server and I want my function to work as expected (not being inhibited like in previous case scenario because we are not in a browser environment).

To conclude, I have a function F that I would like to execute *if it is in browser environment OR a server environment when in an endpoint (but not a server environment when in a page)*.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, especially not in a way that wouldn't uncomfortably couple your code to the underlying tools like the bundler. That said, if your function does 2 different things, it sounds to me like it should really be 2 functions. Which would also probably solve your problem: you would know the correct one to use, because when you're writing the code, _you_ know if you're writing isomorphic or server-side only code. What's your use case for this?

Comment: I updated the question to add context. I also think this is not possible yet. Using two functions would work but that's not elegant. You would have two functions with different names but that do exactly the same, and the user should be careful to not mix one with the other depending on the situation :/ Bad programming design

Comment: Can't you simply add a condition *in the Svelte page* (not in your function) to only call your function when you're in a browser (through `$app/env`'s `browser`)? This way your function will only get called from the browser or from an endpoint, never from a page being server-rendered?

Comment: I'm creating a library so I would like the users not to have to add the `if (browser) ...` condition themselves, but maybe that's the best solution indeed. Thanks for the idea!